# fslint-gui won't launch

Tags: python, gtk

still new to Linux, it has replaced Windows as my preferred OS, but I'm still not as fluent as I'd like to be. Hopefully someone can steer me in the right direction.

OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (all up to date). I'd like to use Fslint to prune duplicate files from a folder, however, Fslint won't launch so I have been using Fdupes instead, but I'd like to fix whatever is broken.

- Whenever I attempt to launch Fslint Janitor from my launcher, nothing happens.
- Whenever I attempt to launch fslint-gui from terminal, the following message appears:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/fslint-gui", line 27, in 
    import gtk ImportError: No module named gtk

I have spent several hours googling, etc but this doesn't appear to be a common problem. Other applications seem to exhibit the same problems and the common solution is to install a variant of Python. However I have done that several times now and no success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking over *fslint* on [github](https://github.com/pixelb/fslint/tree/master/doc), it appears to be a python2 project with a few dependencies based upon the version of fslint you have installed. It specifically calls out the following for version 2.4:

- GTK      >= 2.4
- python   >= 2.6
- libglade >= 2.4
- pygtk2   >= 2.4

However, the latest *PyGTK* package I could find on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/PyGTK/) was version 2.24.  You can easily install that with:

```
pip install pygtk
```

Additionally, you could also install version 2.24 from the Ubuntu repository with:

```
sudo apt install python-gtk2
```

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and looking at *fslint* in the Ubuntu repository it shows:

> Depends: python (>= 2.3), python-gtk2 (>= 2.4), python-glade2, findutils (>= 4.1.1)

As a last resort, you could do a `sudo apt install fslint` or individually apt install the above dependencies.  I would attempt the pip install first before apt but it's there as an option.  Hope that helps point you in the right direction.